# Sharepoint Hosted App, Javascript and Permissions

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app

I've deployed a sharepoint hosted app with custom javascript. When I access my devsite with administrator I can use my app. When accessing with another user the js-files aren't loaded in my apppart. When accessing the app with my user directly I get the logindialog three times and after that the page is blank.

I looked for disableloopbackcheck but thats not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that Internet Explorer "Local Intranet" Sites have been added to each computer you use:
Go to: Tools — Internet Options — Security Tab

Click the “Local intranet” icon to select it

Click the “Sites” button, then click the “Advanced” button

Add the following as “Local intranet” sites:
https://abc.edu
https://acad.edu

Refer:http://social.education.purdue.edu/edit/2011/03/sharepoint-pw-prompts/